# How to check if mention has a role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have been making a mute command for my discord bot and it suddenly.... didn't work in the part of the

```js
if (msg.content.startsWith("!mute")) {
    if (!msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MEMBERS"))
        return msg.channel.send(`You don't have permision to mute members!`);

    let target = msg.mentions.members.first();

    let taggedId = target.id;
    var role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "Muted");
    if (!role) return msg.channel.send("There is no Muted role on the server");

    //The part it didn't work////////////

    if (taggedId.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === "Muted"))
        return msg.channel.send("The member is already muted!");

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (target.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"))
        return msg.channel.send(`The target is an Admin`);

    if (!target) return msg.channel.send(`I couldn't find your target!`);

    target.roles.add(role);

    msg.channel.send(`Muted ${target} Succesfully!`);
}
```

And I get this error:

```
/home/runner/Bot/index.js:289
    if(taggedId.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Muted")) return msg.channel.send('The member is already muted!')
                      ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
        at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Bot/index.js:289:19)
```

I did my best but it was no worth it please if anyone knows help me!

Comment: `taggedId` is a string. It obviously doesn't have a `roles` property. Use `target` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `roles` of a `string` (`taggedId`) which contains the `ID` of the mentioned `user`.

If you want to access the `roles` you have to use your `target` variable because this contains the `GuildMember`:

So insted of this:

```js
if(taggedId.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Muted")) return msg.channel.send('The member is already muted!')
```

You should do this:

```
if(target.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Muted")) return msg.channel.send('The member is already muted!')
```

Comment: You are some kind of genus the code worked I will cry, it was too fast I just reloaded the page after I made it to see an angel!

Comment: @Hassan_BH So you fixed by yourself?

Comment: Glad to hear that :)